# Does a magnetic field propagate or radiate outward from an inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the magnetic field around an inductor propagate indefinitely or does it collapse on itself. For example: if you were to turn the current on and off an inductor would the magnetic field propagate outward weakening as the distance grew until it became nothing but elementary particles or would it collapse back on the inductor? In other words, could an inductor replicate a traveling magnetic field.

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327100/do-we-get-radiowaves-if-the-antenna-is-a-loop-or-a-coil)

Answer (score -1):

> Does the magnetic field around an inductor propagate indefinitely or does it collapse on itself.

It is not the worst idea to first investigate what happens with an induced electric field. A macroscopic electric field is created by the separation of elementary charges [electrons] and represents nothing more than the sum of the electric fields of these charges. If the potential difference of the source is switched off, the separation is cancelled and the electrons are distributed evenly with the protons again.

[In addition to electrostatics, which assumes the ideal case of motionless charges, the emission of electromagnetic radiation of moving charges naturally plays a role. This radiation, in which a magnetic and an electric field propagate simultaneously, is neglected here. It should only be noted that the detachment of only the electrical or magnetic components was never observed.]

Could the induction of a macroscopic magnetic field be considered in the same way as electrical induction? If we assume for a moment that the macroscopic magnetic field would be caused by the alignment of the magnetic dipoles of the electrons, then when the current in a coil is switched off, the magnetic moments of the electrons will fall back in their equally distributed directions. Consequently, the macroscopic magnetic field is not radiated but simply returns to its natural disordered state.

> In other words, could an inductor replicate a traveling magnetic field.

No, neither an electric nor a magnetic field is capable of permanently removing itself from its subatomic particles.

Comment: Wrong answer. A changing electric field gives rise to a magnetic field which gives rise to an electric field etc. Antennas of radio transmitters work that way.

Comment: @Pieter The question was not about EM radiation (which I mentioned too in my answer) but about travelling away magnetic field.

Comment: Also the near field propagates. It will produce a magnetic pulse that is traveling outward from the source. That pulse will continue after the current was switched off. At large distances the EM-wave will dominate (the part that you neglected).